# MinTTL, MaxTTL and DefaultTTL should follow order MinTTL less than or equal to DefaultTTL less than or equal to MaxTTL

Tags: python, amazon-cloudfront, boto3

I have a python script, that copies existing CloudFront distribution and its settings to a different AWS account.

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cf.py", line 105, in <module>
    setup_cloudfront(j)
  File "cf.py", line 90, in setup_cloudfront
    metropolis_client.create_distribution(DistributionConfig=config)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 312, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 601, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidTTLOrder: An error occurred (InvalidTTLOrder) when calling the CreateDistribution operation: MinTTL, MaxTTL and DefaultTTL should follow order MinTTL less than or equal to DefaultTTL less than or equal to MaxTTL
```

this is part of the code

```
def setup_cloudfront(j):
    config = deepcopy(DISTRO_CONFIG)
    config['CallerReference'] = j['CallerReference']
    config['Aliases'] = j['Aliases']
    config['CacheBehaviors'] = j['CacheBehaviors']
    config['Origins'] = j['Origins']
    config['DefaultCacheBehavior'] = j['DefaultCacheBehavior']
    config['DefaultCacheBehavior']['MinTTL'] = 0
    config['DefaultCacheBehavior']['MaxTTL'] = 31536000
    config['DefaultCacheBehavior']['DefaultTTL'] = 86400
    config['PriceClass'] = j['PriceClass']
    config['Enabled'] = j['Enabled']
    # config['HttpVersion'] = j['HttpVersion']
    config['IsIPV6Enabled'] = j['IsIPV6Enabled']
    print(config['CallerReference'], config['Aliases'], config['DefaultCacheBehavior'])
    client.create_distribution(DistributionConfig=config)
```

any advice is much appreciated

Comment: You don't appear to be examining the configuration of behaviors other than the default.  There can be up to 25 cache behaviors per distribution.  Dump the entire `config` structure and inspect for other cache behaviors, which may have problems.

Comment: yes this was the issue, thanks